# Parsing Html from string into document

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to parse Html code from string into a document and start appending each node at a time to the real dom.
After some research i have encountered this api :

```
DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument()
```

which works great but if some node has descendants than i need to first append the node and only after its in the real dom than i should start appending its descendants , i think i can use

```
document.importNode(externalNode, deep);
```

with the deep value set to false in order to copy only the parent node.
so my approach is good for this case and how should i preserve my order of appended nodes so i wont append the same node twice? 
and one more problem is in some cases i need to add more html code into a specific location (for example after some div node) and continue appending , any idea how to do that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOMParser for that:

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString('<h1>Hello World</h1>', 'text/html');

document.body.appendChild(doc.documentElement);
```

But if you want to append the same thing multiple times, you will have better performances using a `template`:

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
const instance = template.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(instance.content);
const instance2 = template.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(instance2.content);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I know about the DOMParser api but it doesn't solve any of the problems i mentioned in my question so unfortunately it wont help me at all

Comment: Sorry this didn't help. I think I don't understand fully your question then. Appending content to a DOM tree from a string is pretty straightforward using the methods I showed you. This can add a whole sub-tree directly with the order preserved. If for some reason you need to append all the nodes manually as you mentioned, you will have to use a TreeWalker and write the append logic yourself. It is usually a anti-pattern to do so as it does not alleviates the performant string parsing from the browser itself

Comment: i do need to append each node separately and if the node contains childrens then i need to append the node without its childrens and then start appending its childrens and so on...